# Positioning a banner on the left side of a site and align banner right to the content

Tags: html, css, banner

I have the content set to 1024px width and aligned to the center. Now I want a banner on the left side. Because the banner can be in different size I have to align the banner to the right side. The banner is wrapped with an anchor. In my example below I used a div instead of an image.

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="banner">
        <a href="#"><div id="background">banner</div></a>
    </div>
    <div id="maincontent">      
        SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
        OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
        MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
        EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
        CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
        OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
        NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
        TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
        EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
        NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
        TTTTTTTTT
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;    
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#background {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;    
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

#banner{
    position: absolute;
    left: -200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;    
    text-align: right;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwRRP/)

`text-align: right;` doesn't make the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `width: 20px` from `#background`

Comment: In this example it works because I'm using a `div` as background. If I switch here in the example to an image it also seems to work. But in reality I have an image without width and height attribute. Here it doesn't work. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I found the error. In my real world scenario `#banner` had no width. So it doesn't worked.